# Liouville's equation is equivalent to the Gauss–Codazzi equations for minimal immersions into the 3-space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, minimal-surfaces

I was going through this wiki page [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_equation) on the Liouville's equation. In that page there is this comment without any source '**Liouville's equation is equivalent to the Gauss–Codazzi equations for minimal immersions into the $3$-space, when the metric is written in isothermal coordinates $z$ such that the Hopf differential is $dz^2$.**'

I am looking for a proof of the above statement. I am not aware whether this is a trivial/well known statement in the literature. I am asking for any source for this or a possible way to approach this proof.

Comment: Two comments. One is that there's a standard, well-known formula for $K$ in an orthogonal parametrization. The second is that when you have a minimal surface, the Gauss map is holomorphic (the surface has an obvious holomorphic structure coming from the conformal metric, and we take $S^2 =\Bbb CP^1$ with the complex structure coming from stereographic projection from the south pole).